# Incremental Build issue of cocos2d-x project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I have successfully built cocos2d-x project in Eclipse, but the problem I'm facing is when I run the project with "Run as Android Application" from eclipse, it compiles all the .cpp source file even though no any changes is made in the source files.

I'm building the project using build_native.sh script from cocos2d-x project using android-ndk (version: android-ndk-r9b).

I've following screenshots from Eclipse build settings.
[image: Build Behaviour]

[image: Build Settings]

Comment: Here you have checked the option `Generate Makefiles automatically`. Therefore insure that your Android.mk and Application.mk files are generating all the time, otherwise whenever mk files changes it will build all cpp files related to project.

Comment: Android.mk files is generated by build_native.sh, which calls my own script to generate makefile, because it contains list of all the .cpp source files, which I don't want to manually write. So, I've created a script which called by build_native.sh, checks all the .cpp files in directory, and dynamically generates Android.mk.

Comment: By the way, I got the answer, auto-generation of makefile is causing all the build process repeating. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Okay for the Make file generation you can create an external builder and attach any script file which generate your Android.mk file with builder and run whenever you need to generate file. I won't recommend any changes to Make files every time you build project.